# Getting Featured Image for all post from RSS feed

Tags: jquery, wordpress, rss

I want to retrieve RSS feed post from http://www.espncricinfo.com/rss/content/story/feeds/4.xml. And I have used RSS Autopilot Plugin for Wordpress.
But, Problem is that the Images they set is using Differ method and javascript.
So, this plugin not able to fetch images for some Post. Any way to fetch images for all post . ?

Answer (score 1):

**very simple using Featured Image In RSS Feed plugin (solution no:1):--**

1.https://wordpress.org/plugins/featured-image-in-rss-feed/

Comment: Not Worked for me.

Comment: Not Any error, But Featured Image not display for some post.

Comment: okay and can you tell me all post Featured Image not show Or some post Featured Image show ?

Comment: Actually, using RSS Autopilot plugin it display some featured image, And I want Featured image for All post. But, This Plugins and code not affect the output. They still not get Featured image for all post.

Comment: okay nd firstly you deactive this plugin then use me provide all solutions.

Comment: and can you send me show post images or not show post screenshot ?

Comment: If I deactivate RSS Autopilot Plugin then How I fetch RSS feed? I mean What I do Exactly?

Comment: firstly deactive this plugin then you clear site all cache and then add code(functions.php)file.

Comment: But, How this Code know the URL of feed ?

Answer (score 1):

**Another solution (solution no:2):--**

open your theme’s functions.php file and add the following code:

```
function rss_post_thumbnail($content) {
global $post;
if(has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) {
$content = '<p>' . get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID) .
'</p>' . get_the_content();
}
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_excerpt_rss', 'rss_post_thumbnail');
add_filter('the_content_feed', 'rss_post_thumbnail');
```

Comment: Not Any error, But Featured Image not display for some post

Answer (score 1):

**Another solution (solution no:3):--**

step 1:--

Install the free “Featured Images in RSS (https://wordpress.org/plugins/featured-images-for-rss-feeds/)” plugin.

step:2:--

Then in your WordPress dashboard click into “Settings” and then into “Featured Images in RSS Feeds.”

Step 3:--

You can then choose the size of your featured image and the positioning/alignment. The default sizes available will be thumbnail, medium, and large which are setup in your WordPress media settings.

Answer (score 1):

**Another solution no:4(try this one)--**

> step:-- 1

Firstly create template(which page show all feed post)

i have create template example like:--

```
<?php
/*
Template Name:feed_post
Description:all show feed post
*/
get_header();
?>
```

```
   <style>
img.attachment-100x100.size-100x100.wp-post-image {
    display: none;
}    
img.attachment-thumbnail.size-thumbnail.wp-post-image {
    display: none;
}
</style>
<?php
$rss=fetch_feed('http://www.espncricinfo.com/rss/content/story/feeds/4.xml');  
//define which post show 
$rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, 10);

foreach($rss_items as $item) 
{
?>
    <a href="<?php echo $item->get_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo $item->get_date('j F Y @ g:i a'); ?>"><?php echo $item->get_title(); ?></a> 

<?php
echo '<div>'.$item->get_description().'</div>';

}
?>
    <?php
get_footer(); 
?>
```

> step:-- 2

```
Using any plugin add Featured Images your feed:--

plugin name:-- 1.Send Images to RSS (https://wordpress.org/plugins/send-images-rss/)

2. Featured Image In Rss Feed (https://wordpress.org/plugins/featured-image-in-rss-feed/)
```